# HTML5 geolocation with GPS fails after phone wake up on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation

I'm building a website which use HTML5 Geolocation API.

In Android's default browser everything works fine, but I have a strange bug which seems to occur only on Android devices.

On the first page load the browser ask me if I accept to share my location and the geolocation feature works as expected.

But if I let the phone fall asleep mode while the page requesting geolocation is open in the browser, then I wake up the phone and reload that page, the geolocation doesn't work anymore. Even if the GPS icon appears in the taskbar and flash normally ..

The error callback gets called with the no service argument, which means the page see the GPS device but cannot read its data.

No matter how many times I refresh the page I always get this error.

However if I go to Settings and clear the geolocation access (the settings that keeps track of which sites have permissions for geolocation), then kill the browser with the task manager, then reload the browser and try again, it start working again.

As for other browsers, I tried Firefox, Dolphin HD and Opera and they all don't work. It ask if I want to share my location, I answer yes and I get the no service error. Again the GPS icon appears and flash in the task bar..

At some point it worked in Dolphin HD and Firefox, but I installed updates and since a while it stopped working.

I get the same behaviour on a Samsung Galaxy SII (And. 2.3) and a Motorolla Milestone (And. 2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was weather problem .. great.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK Manager and installed "Google API"

then give permission to in Android Manifest:

```
  android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
  android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
  android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
  android.permission.INTERNET
```

then "Run" the Application

Comment: I've removed your signature. Please don't post that; all that information is contained in your profile, if you wish to put it there.